# load sculpt mask from file?

Tags: sculpting, masking

Is there any option in blender to load a sculpt mask from a file?

Let's say I want only affect the sharp edges of a mesh in multires sculpting and flatten them (the edges of a stone sculpture, for example). I would create a cavity map, load that into sculpting mode as a mask and could merrily proceed to sculpt only the sharp edges.

Comment: That would be just some sort of reference and wouldn't have any masking capabilities. My main idea is speeding up the workflow.

Comment: Seems that I wasn't clear enough. Do you want to have possibility to sculpt using [image texture as a mask for your sculpting brush](https://i.imgur.com/w4TJkry.jpg) ?

Comment: No. Imagine a hi-poly model of an old worn stone sculpture. The sharp edges would be withered. Now we assign a cavity texture to that model which "masks" sharp edges white, while everything else would be black (masked out, not affected). Now imagine how fast it would be to sculpt over the sharp edges without changing the rest of the model.

Instant worn edges in hi-poly to be baked onto a normal map.

Comment: Well, the problem seems to be that image texture can't be applied to sculpt brush according to UV map. Still you could try execute *Dirty Vertex Colors* in Vertex Paint mode with appropriate setup, use [Vertex Weight To Vertex Colors](http://www.swineworld.org/2015/02/transfer-vertex-weights-to-vertex-colors.html) addon to transfer colors into vertex group, add Smooth modifier and choose that group in options of the modifier; it will smoothen only given vertices, according to your setup.